# Bash - start and monitor an application using a wathcDog

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, watchdog

I'm writing a watchDog script which start my application and restart it while it been detected as down (according the process PID).

**code:**

```
while  [ $pid ]; do
pid=$(getPID)
#if server App is down start it!
if [ -z "$pid" ]; then
        echo -e "`date` [INFO]: watchDog activated -> starting service since was been deteced as down!\n" >> $watchDogLogger 2>$1
        startApp > /dev/null 2>$1
        pid=$(getPID)
fi
done
```

the issue is when a user start the application with the watchDog (watchdog start) because the while loop the console is "stuck" and i can't continue to using it.
i know that i can't to run the watchDog as background job (watchDog start &) and then get the console back but it make me troubles since when i want to stop it (watchDog stop) it indeed stop the application but the first watchDop job (watchDog start) is still live.

is there any other way to start the watchDog and get the consile back?

Thank you!

Comment: This really isn't an answer to your question but checkout pm2. It sounds like it does what you want: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2 There's also system tools that will help you do this like https://wiki.debian.org/systemd

Comment: Btw: I suggest to start your app this way: `while true; do echo "starting service"; startApp; done`